# Recording microphone audio with Haskell

Tags: haskell, audio, sdl-2

I am working on some voice recognition software as my first Haskell project. I am looking for something something that could work cross-platform. My plan is as follows:

1. Record audio as a .wav file
2. Use https://hackage.haskell.org/package/flac to convert the .wav file to a FLAC file.
3. Send a speech API request to Google's Speech API (as can be seen here https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/quickstart).
4. Receive response and interpret it.

However, I am currently somewhat stuck on step 1 as it seems rather difficult to record microphone input in Haskell.

Since this is a learning experience I wanted to try to find something simple that I could understand quite easily. After some googling I found this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169577/sound-recorder-based-on-sdl2, which uses Haskell SDL2 bindings and Codec.Audio.Wave. I tried copying the code to see if it would work, but alas it did not. I did not have any errors with running the program, but when I tried playing the wave file, nothing happened and it seemed completely empty. Nothing seems to have been recorded, as the file size is only 44 bytes.

I figured the issue was the SDL open device spec not being able to find a suitable recording device, so I tried checking the frequency to see if my microphone wasn't able to handle 48000 Hz and then since that didn't help (it is 96000 Hz max) I tried messing around with the device channels, but that did not help either.

The problem is not with my microphone since I tried recording some audio with arecord (on Arch Linux), which worked just fine. As I said, this is my first Haskell project and I am a bit of a newbie and although I do have experience in other languages it is completely possible that I have done something really silly.

I am not opposed to any solutions not involving SDL2, but as I am looking for something (hopefully) simple and cross-platform, this seemed like a good fit.

Comment: If you're anyway just _saving a file to be sent to Google_, why do you need Haskell at all? I'm a bit reminded of https://xkcd.com/1060/. Might as well just _use `arecord`_. — That said, I'd be interested to hear if something like [conduit-audio](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-audio) is up to recording directly in Haskell nowadays. This _should_ not be difficult...

Comment: Well, I am using Haskell because my ultimate goal is to create a kind of personal assistant (like Alexa or Cortana) so I need to be able to process the information afterwards. Also, this is a learning project and I want it to be cross platform.